# Suppress request output with Docker & Dinghy

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dinghy

I'm using [dinghy](https://github.com/codekitchen/dinghy) with docker and docker-compose. I've got a [docker image for fake_sqs](https://github.com/link664/fakesqs-docker), which I'm loading in my docker-compose like so:

```
fakesqs:
  image: link664/fakesqs-docker
  command: bundle exec fake_sqs -n fakesqs -p 4568
  environment:
    VIRTUAL_HOST: aws.docker
```

I also have a poller script that runs and connects to the image:

```
poller:
  build: poller/.
  command: script/poller
  volumes:
    - ./poller:/app
  links:
    - fakesqs
  environment:
    AWS_QUEUE_NAME: my-queue
    AWS_ENDPOINT: http://fakesqs:4568/
```

This all works happily. The poller can read from fake_sqs and it's all good. The issue I'm having is that each time the poller hits the queue (which is several times per second), it logs the request to stdout:

```
fakesqs_1    | [2016-07-27 07:59:29] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
fakesqs_1    | [2016-07-27 07:59:29] INFO  ruby 2.2.3 (2015-08-18) [x86_64-linux]
fakesqs_1    | == Sinatra (v1.4.7) has taken the stage on 4568 for development with backup from WEBrick
fakesqs_1    | [2016-07-27 07:59:29] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1 port=4568
poller_1     | Creating queue my-queue
fakesqs_1    | 172.17.0.11 - - [27/Jul/2016:08:00:00 UTC] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 273
fakesqs_1    | - -> /
poller_1     | Initializing poller for queue http://fakesqs:4568/my-queue
poller_1     | Polling ...
fakesqs_1    | 172.17.0.11 - - [27/Jul/2016:08:00:00 UTC] "POST /my-queue HTTP/1.1" 200 221
fakesqs_1    | - -> /my-queue
fakesqs_1    | 172.17.0.11 - - [27/Jul/2016:08:00:01 UTC] "POST /my-queue HTTP/1.1" 200 221
fakesqs_1    | - -> /my-queue
fakesqs_1    | 172.17.0.11 - - [27/Jul/2016:08:00:01 UTC] "POST /my-queue HTTP/1.1" 200 221
fakesqs_1    | - -> /my-queue
fakesqs_1    | 172.17.0.11 - - [27/Jul/2016:08:00:01 UTC] "POST /my-queue HTTP/1.1" 200 221
fakesqs_1    | - -> /my-queue
fakesqs_1    | 172.17.0.11 - - [27/Jul/2016:08:00:01 UTC] "POST /my-queue HTTP/1.1" 200 221
fakesqs_1    | - -> /my-queue
```

How do I suppress this request logging without totally suppressing STDOUT?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll need to extend the fakesqs image and adjust the logging levels. You can't control this from Compose unless you want to just disable all stdout logging.

Comment: How do I adjust the logging levels in the Dockerfile?

Comment: It would be application specific. fakesqs probably takes a config setting to adjust the logging.